# How to combine/merge the outputs of 2 pymongo queries?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Please can someone help with the below question.

I have 2 pymongo queries, whose output needs to be merged/combined

1.)One to find the the distinct employees names and the count of number of stocks they hold

**Query 1:**

```
from bson.son import SON
pipeline = [
    
{"$unwind":"$EmpName"},
{"$group": {"_id": "$EmpName", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
{"$sort": SON([("count", -1), ("_id", -1)])}
]
pprint.pprint(list(qatClient.get_database(dbName).get_collection(EmpCol).aggregate(pipeline)))
```

Output:
[{'_id': 'SOFR', 'count': 88},
{'_id': 'LOHR', 'count': 59}]

2.)Second query to find the empname, approved by, marked, and expirydate of trade from a different collection

**Query 2:**

```
docCur = qatClient.get_database(dbName).get_collection(sapCol).find({'currentTo' : currentToDate},{"_id" : 0,"EmpName":1, "Approvedby" : 1, "Expdate" : 1, "marked" : 1})

for doc in docCur:
    printBson(doc)
```

Output:
{
"EmpName": "SOFR",
"Approvedby": "4511",
"marked": "Y",
"Expdate": {
"$date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00Z"
}
}
{
"EmpName": "LOHR",
"Approvedby": "4508",
"marked": "Y",
"Expdate": {
"$date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00Z"
}
}

**Actual output We need is:**

```
'_id': 'SOFR', 'count': 88,"EmpName": "SOFR","Approvedby": "4511","marked": "Y","Expdate": {"$date": "2021-09-29T00:00:00Z"}
```

Combine 2 outputs , the emp name would be repeated twice which is also ok. Sorry, for the lengthy question, the JSON is too big and i am a beginner. Lookup is expensive on these collections.

How to combine the outputs or the query can be merged. Please advise

Thank you in advance,
:)

Comment: Have you checked out [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/)?

Comment: No, can you help me with some more details about it please

Comment: Please check out the official document link I provided to understand the concept of how $unionWith help you combine 2 queries' output. For your case, your query 2 seems can be converted into a simple aggregation with a $match and $project. You can then put this simple converted aggregation into the $unionWith.